# Composite foreign key and DDL generation in JPA 2

Tags: java, foreign-keys, jpa-2.0, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to create a class with a foreign composite key and everything works fine, except that the DDL generation doesn't create indeces as expected.

I will explain better with some code; the part of the code I'm trying to implement is the ribbon awarding: a `User` can have many `Ribbon`s and a `Ribbon` can have many `User`s (many-to-many).

`Ribbon` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ribbon")
public class Ribbon
{
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(
                    name = "id",
                    column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 4)
            ),
            @AttributeOverride(
                    name = "level",
                    column = @Column(name = "level", nullable = false)
            )
    })
    @EmbeddedId
    RibbonId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "ribbon")
    private Set<UserHasRibbon> userHasRibbonSet;

    // ...
}
```

`RibbonId` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class RibbonId implements Serializable
{
    public int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public UserLevel level;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`UserHasRibbon` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_has_ribbon")
public class UserHasRibbon
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 16)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="ribbon_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="ribbon_level", referencedColumnName="level", nullable = false)
    })
    private Ribbon ribbon;

    @Column(name = "earned_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date earnedDate;

    // ...
}
```

It's pretty straightforward and everything is working perfectly. The only problem is that I noticed that the automatic DDL generation didn't create the indeces in the `user_has_ribbon` table:

- `ribbon_id` has an index but is not linked to `ribbon`.`id`
- `ribbon_level` doesn't have an index at all
- `user_id` is correct, has an index linked to `user`.`id`

I know that the DDL generation should be disabled for production, I'm just wondering why it's not behaving as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: How it is behaving depends on which JPA implementation you are using. A thing to consider is why you are wondering this - of course it is good to tinker - but in this case I'm pretty sure you should be tinkering with(in) the JPA implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @esej. The JPA implementation is Hibernate and the database is MySQL. I found the "solution", see my own answer to my question. Silly me... Thanks!

Comment: Cool, please accept your own answer. (So people looking for questions to answer doesn't find this one.)

Comment: I know, but I have to wait 2 days to accept it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that JPA **did** create a composite index on the two columns (`ribbon_id` and `ribbon_level`) and it's working fine. I got confused because phpMyAdmin doesn't show relations correctly when it's about composite indeces...